# Getting Error in flow when Using input field in lWC . Works fine on record page but getting error on in flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 2140377489)

error ID: 2140377489

We are getting this error when we try to use lighting component in Flow . This Component works fine on record page.  Our Component has two HTML input fields , If we remove those fields then we are not getting this Error in flow.

If we use any other standard along with our component in flow then we are not getting this Error .[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Start the flow in Debug mode to see more if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Well sharing a bit of code will help, but just to make sure please check the following:

Steps to add LWC in Flow

- To make LWC available in Flow is to add lightning__FlowScreen target in the metafile of the component.
- Add targetConfig with property for lightning__FlowScreen target to pass a parameter from Flow to LWC
- Annotate Lightning Web Component properties with @api which will get the data from Flow.